# Getting class name instead of property value in XAML binding with TabControl

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have the following `TabControl` in my XAML where I'm trying to get the tab headers to show the Name property of my `Sequence` class. My ViewModel returns an `ObservableCollection<Sequence>`. But for some reason I get "Sequencer.Common.SequenceDocument.Sequence" appearing in the tab header instead.

The `Sequence` class has a `Name` property and I know it returns the proper name but am I missing something in the `ItemHeader` binding?

```
<dx:DXTabControl x:Name="TabControl" 
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Sequences}"
                 SelectionChanged="TabControl_OnSelectionChanged">
    <dx:DXTabControl.View>
        <dx:TabControlMultiLineView HeaderLocation="Bottom"/>
    </dx:DXTabControl.View>
    <dx:DXTabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="dx:DXTabItem">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}"/>
        </Style>
    </dx:DXTabControl.ItemContainerStyle>

    <!--Content-->
    <dx:DXTabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <views:DxTaskList x:Name="Tasklst" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </dx:DXTabControl.ItemTemplate>                                    
</dx:DXTabControl>
```

Comment: For debugging purpose, you could add an Converter to the `Value`-binding, and inspect where the `Name` value is coming from. Anything else here would be guessing. What IS this DXTabControl? Your own? Thrid party library?

Comment: It's a third-party library (DevExpress)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You using ItemContainerStyle that is used to set the style for each item of list.

You need to define the template for this and your binding should look like

```
<!--Content-->
<dx:DXTabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            <views:DxTaskList x:Name="Tasklst" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</dx:DXTabControl.ItemTemplate>
```

the value of setter property in style cannot be binded.

But binding Name to the textblock would definitely give you all the Name in the Sequence class contained in sequences Collection.

Comment: This seemed to have done the trick, however, I still needed to override the ToString() method of my Sequence class, so that it returned the Name.

Comment: saved muh life bruh... saved it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the `ItemContainerStyle`, which is, according to the [DevExpress documentation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#Silverlight/DevExpressXpfCoreDXTabControl_ItemContainerStyletopic):

> a style applied to the container element generated for each tab item

But what you want to achieve, is *to get the tab headers to show the Name property of my Sequence class*.

**In order to complete this**, you need to set the `ItemHeaderTemplate` property of the `DXTabControl`:

```
<dx:DXTabControl>
    <dx:DXTabControl.ItemHeaderTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </dx:DXTabControl.ItemHeaderTemplate>
</dx:DXTabControl>
```

**But why did your class name show up in the header?**

As you didn't specify the header template for the tab items, the control used the `ToString()` / string representation of your class.
Normally, the string representation is the full qualified class name.
And due to this, you see the class name, rather than the `Name` property.

Overloading the `ToString` method would also solve your problem, but **it is not** the real solution.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `Sequences.Name` (or whatever the name of your property is) in your `ItemsSource`?

So it looks like:

```
<dx:DXTabControl x:Name="TabControl" 
 ItemsSource="{Binding Sequences.Name}"
 SelectionChanged="TabControl_OnSelectionChanged">
```

My hunch is that you're binding to the class itself, which is "Sequencer.Common.SequenceDocument.Sequence", (just like how if you did Sequence.toString()) and it will return the object name itself.

The binding has to be to a property, here's a good tutorial on [binding stuff](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2012/04/20/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-databinding-in-wpf-silverlight-and-wp7-part-two.html), you might want to look under 'The Property Path Syntax' section.